# Polymorphic association with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

We have models as below...

```
class Post
  has_many: :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Media
  has_many: :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment
  belongs_to: :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to: :post, foreign_key::post_id, foreign_type: 'Post'
end
```

Exampale

```
Post1 has Comment3 => {id: 3, text: "Some comment 3", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: 'Post'}
Media2 has Comment4 => {id: 4, text: "Some comment 4", commentable_id: 2, commentable_type: 'Media'}

When I want to access Comment3.post it gives result as expected.
But When some how want access Comment4.post it brings an object from post table which has id = 2, but expected nil, coz Comment4 does not belongs to any post.
```

We can get from below method inside Comment model, but want as an association.

```
def post
  self.commentable if self.commentable_type == 'Post'
end
```

Could not get what I expected.., Please help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your approach

```
def post
  self.commentable if self.commentable_type == 'Post'
end
```

But if you really need it in the association way, then you can try with

```
belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :commentable_id, foreign_type: :commentable_type, polymorphic: true
```

OR

```
belongs_to :post, -> (record){ record.commentable_type == 'Post' ? joins(:comments).where(comments: {commentable_type: 'Post'}) : where("false") }, foreign_key: :commentable_id
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: This will not solve the problem actually.
When I did ```Comment4.post```

You can see the query 
```SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`commentable_id` = `posts`.`id` AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Post' WHERE `posts`.`id` = '2' AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'Post' LIMIT 1```

Comment: And it returned an object instead of ```nil```.

Comment: @RAJASHARMA, I have update my answer, now please check.